# How to hide file with no extension that is generated after compiling 'c' or 'c++' language code in Vs-code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using Vs-Code to study c++ and whenever I run the code with code-runner, a new file appears in my explorer tab with the same name as my .cpp file but with no extension. Causes a lot of clutter to my files. I have tried excluding the file with:

"**/. ": true

but this does not get rid of these files and in fact it does nothing.

"**/.*": true  (This gets rid of all the files, so I know the exclude json is working)

Can anyone help?

Thanks
Clan

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're using **code runner** in **VS code** to run the cpp programme (but you can do it with any editor/runner if you know a little bit about terminal and configuration).

1. Go to settings in Code Editor
2. Search executorMap in search box
3. Click edit in settings.json

   - You will see code like:

   `"code-runner.executorMap" : { "cpp": "cd $dir && g++ $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt" }`

   - Change it to this:

   `"code-runner.executorMap" : { "cpp": "cd $dir && g++ $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt && rm ./$fileNameWithoutExt" }`

**Explanation:**
rm is used to delete the file, and `&&` is used to run the command after executing all previous commands, so the *$fileNameWithoutExt (variable storing name of the executable file)* will be deleted once the program is finished.
As a result, the file will be deleted after each execution.

**Note:**
you can add `&& rm ./$fileNameWithoutExt` at the end of any command so you just need to find the line that is executed when you run the code and check the variable name storing the name of the file.

Answer (score 1):

Using the period symbol since the file does not have an extension so no '.'. You will need to add the exact file names in the settings.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wonder if the compiler can be tweaked to put this file somewhere else? (Not experienced enough to know how to tackle that one! :)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to hide those files without extension with somewhat of an hack.

I added following glob patterns

```
**/??[!.]
**/???[!.]
**/????[!.]
**/?????[!.]
... and so on

//hide all the files with 2,3,4,5 characters in name not followed by a '.'
```

However it is bad because it will **also hides the folders.**
Would like someone to improve on this solution though.

Answer (score -1):

You can hide the files without extension by some changes. Just follow the below steps:

1. Press **f1**.
2. Enter **settings.json** and choose the second option which is **Open Setting(JSON)**.
3. Then find the **"code-runner.executorMap"** in the **setting.json** file if not exist then create one.
4. Under the **"code-runner.executorMap"** change **fileNameWithoutExt** with **fileNameWithExt** under "c" and "cpp".

[image: Before changing file name]

[image: After changing file name]

5. Then Save and exit file.

Now after the above steps executable files or compiled files generated  with **cppWithExt** and **cWithExt** extension which you can easily hide by adding them into **Exclude** in settings.

[image: picture showing GUI]

Comment: I tried this, this doesn't work. Looks like we need to give some regex in order to remove files without extension.

Comment: @AshutoshTiwari can you please explain it what didn't work.

Comment: I am looking to remove that cpp generated non-extension files from the vs code, I don't want them to appear on the VS Code Explorer, the method you have shown here doesn't work.